# How can I modify the template for generating setters in CLion?

Tags: clion, setter

In CLion, we can generate setters from fields by: Code -> Generate... -> Setter. But how can I modify the template for the code generation to change, for example, the generated setter parameter name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [I've got it confirmed from JetBrains that this is currently not possible in CLion.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009268640-How-can-I-modify-the-template-for-generating-setters-in-CLion-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can not fully customize it, but you can change some attributes of it under `Editor > Code Style > C/C++` Like if prefixes should be added.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. The options in the code style options are very limited, however, and the parameter name setting that I need is not included.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought, I wish they would use something like live templates instead.